# Monetizar Windows Forms C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Olá, desculpem não ser uma pergunta diretamente ligada á uma linguagem, mas procurei bastante e não achei, alguém conhece alguma biblioteca como o Ad Mediator para ser usada em Windows Forms? Como monetizo/coloco anúncios no meu software de formulários? Podem me dizer se há ferramentas para isso, e se possível dar um exemplo?

Comment: Tente usar um WebBrowser com algum anúncio do tipo os do google, usando isso, se você desejar, tem como fazer algo um pouco mais "ilegal", simulando cliques no anúncio, etc..
Olhe o [AdSense](http://www.google.com.br/adsense/start/) do google.

Comment: Eu pensei nisso, tentei com alguns desses serviços, mas tem de enviar um link de site, e alterar esse site para que eles possam validar e daí sim valer os anúncios, e aí que mora o problema, não tenho site, tenho blog no WordPress, mas não vale.. Há algum serviço que não necessite de confirmação? Esse método ilegal não é necessário kk, porque o software será acessado por milhares de usuários, porém não quero desenvolver o treco 100% free, tenho que lucrar com anúncios kk

Comment: O próprio google também oferece uma plataforma pra monetização em aplicativos android, [AdMob](http://www.google.com.br/ads/admob), sem precisar de um site, outra opção seria o [SmaAto](https://www.smaato.com/)

Comment: O AdMob seria somente para apps, pois existe a referencia "Ad Mediator" Que conecta os anúncios, vou ar uma olhada nesse outro.

Answer (score 3):

Leonardo, porque você não monta imagens de propaganda e as exibe em um Painel (ou paineis), trocando a cada evento do Timer.

Pode ler um XML de qualquer lugar da internet com todas as imagens e armazenar no banco de dados (sqlite, por exemplo), mantendo ele atualizado para o caso de seu cliente ficar offline. Conta os cliques pela aplicação mesmo incrementando alguma coluna e de tempos em tempos, envia o XML para seu site para totalizar, zerando os cliques locais.

Se eu fosse fazer alguma coisa comercial para Windows Forms pensaria em algo mais ou menos assim. Há anos atrás cheguei até a fazer alguma coisa assim em Delphi, seguindo esta linha de pensamento.

Answer (score -3):

Windows Forms está cada vez mais em desuso, por isso acho difícil encontrar algo do tipo. 
No entanto, é plenamente possível monetizar aplicativos(tanto para pcs, tablets ou Mobile).
A própia Microsoft já desenvolve uma iniciativa do tipo.
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/monetize/ads

Olhe e veja.

Comment: Sim, porém o PubCenter, ou agora o Monetize da Microsoft, funciona só com o SDK Ads, e creio que não dá suporte a Windows Forms.

Comment: Da onde você tirou essa informação ?